# Flutter: Reading and merging firestore data by date

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to merge the data I'm reading from Cloud Firestore by date. My aim is to read all the documents from Cloud Firestore, then place all documents of a certain date under ONE `ExpansionTile`. i.e. One `ExpansionTile` per date, and each `ExpansionTile` may contain many individual documents depending on how much was uploaded that day.

I'm having no issues reading the data from Cloud Firestore, but I am struggling to figure out how to organise and merge the documents by date once I have the information at hand. Keeping in mind that there will be multiple different dates and all with different amounts of documents per date.

As seen in the picture below, I currently have three documents with the same date, and therefore three different `ExpansionTiles` when creating them in the app. I am looking to convert these three into one `ExpansionTile`

[image]

I am currently reading the data from Cloud Firestore by date using the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package:

```
    //Retrieves firebase data of all orders done in the past
  Stream<OrderHistoryState> _loadOrderHistory() async* {
    try {
      _orderSubscription?.cancel();

      var orderHistory = Firestore.instance
          .collection('orders')
          .orderBy('date', descending: true);

      _orderSubscription = orderHistory.snapshots().listen(
        (event) {
          if (event.documents.length > 0) {
            add(OrderHistoryUpdate(
              documents: event.documents,
            ));
          } else {
            print("No Order to Load");
            add(NoOrderHistory());
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error with Tracking Status, $e");
          add(ErrorOrderHistory());
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you who may be curious, this was my solution to the problem. It may be a bit long winded, so any suggestions to shorten/improve it are still greatly appreciated:

```
                  //Make sure that there are documents within firebase
                  if (state.orderHistoryDocuments.length != 0) {
                    //Adding the first document manually so that
                    //the forloop section has something to compare dates
                    //This listForEachDate is for storing a collection
                    //of all documents of one date
                    listForEachDate = [state.orderHistoryDocuments[0].data];
                    //listOfDateLists is a list of all listForEachDate
                    //This gives us a list of lists with the documents
                    //separated by date i.e.
                    //[[date1, date1], [date2], [date3, date3, date3], etc]
                    listOfDateLists = [];

                    //i = 1 because index 0 already added above
                    for (int i = 1;
                        i < state.orderHistoryDocuments.length;
                        i++) {
                      //If the current index's date matches that of the previous
                      //index's date, then add it to the listForEachDate
                      if (state.orderHistoryDocuments[i]
                              .data["dateCreated"] ==
                          state.orderHistoryDocuments[i - 1]
                              .data["dateCreated"]) {
                        listForEachDate
                            .add(state.orderHistoryDocuments[i].data);
                        //If [index]date does not match [index - 1]date
                        //Then add the current listForEachDate to the
                        //listOfDateLists i.e. add sublist to list of lists
                      } else {
                        listOfDateLists.add(listForEachDate);
                        //Clear the listForEachDate so that we can create
                        //a new clean list of new dates
                        listForEachDate = [];
                        //Add the new date to the listForEachDate
                        //so that the process can start again
                        listForEachDate
                            .add(state.orderHistoryDocuments[i].data);
                      }
                    }
                    //Once the document has been iterated through,
                    //Add to the big list.
                    listOfDateLists.add(listForEachDate);
                  }
```